# Opportunities in theoretical computer science

Tags: phd, computer-science, internship

I am currently doing MS in Natural Sciences, is there a way I can get into research about Complexity theory. A phD might be difficult but are there any chances of a research intern so I can build my base for phD ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You will have a master degree, and therefore you have the main criteria to apply for a Ph.D. You should apply for a Ph.D. position because you have a year to check the domain before start contributing to the field.

Now that you want to work on the complexity theory, find a supervisor who did publish number of papers/journals about the matter. Then, try to communicate with him/her to see if he/she can offer you a place in his/her research group.